# Change animation transition

Tags: ios, animation, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

I got an app with `NavigationController`. How can i change animation transition style of `pushViewController` and `popToViewController`?

UPD

I created category like in @lawicko answer. But i got error when i am trying to call function

[self.navigationController pushViewController:places withCustomTransition:CustomViewAnimationTransitionPush subtype:CustomViewAnimationSubtypeFromLeft];

error is : "use of undeclared identifier 'CustomViewAnimationTransitionPush'"

Where should i declare this part:

```
typedef enum {
    CustomViewAnimationTransitionNone,
    CustomViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft,
    CustomViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight,
    CustomViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp,
    CustomViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown,
    CustomViewAnimationTransitionFadeIn,
    CustomViewAnimationTransitionMoveIn,
    CustomViewAnimationTransitionPush,
    CustomViewAnimationTransitionReveal
} CustomViewAnimationTransition;
```

Write now i declare it in `UINavigationController+Additions.h`

UPD 2: One more new error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CATransition", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UINavigationController+Additions.o
  "_kCATransition", referenced from:
```

and same errors foor all _kCATransitions

Comment: Did you try this?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699882/can-i-curl-down-a-page-on-popviewcontrolleranimated

Comment: thats ok, but i want animation like in back button.. but set it for pushViewController

Comment: I don't really understand. You want the animation that you have when you click on back (popViewController) to be the one when you push the view (pushViewController)?

Comment: yes! i wanna animation like horizontal sliding. but with direction to left

Answer (score 19):

Check out this `UINavigationController` category that I created. It allows you pushing and popping with pretty much every possible transition, and also supports subtypes for QuartzCore transitions, which will allow you to do exactly what you want - push the view from the left. Do it like this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[[MyController alloc] init] withCustomTransition:CustomViewAnimationTransitionPush subtype:CustomViewAnimationSubtypeFromLeft];
```

The code is below. The first part you need to put in the header part:

```
// IMPORTANT - basic transitions like flip and curl are local, they reside only in animation block. Core animations however,
// once assigned to the layer, stay until changed or reset (by assigning nil as layer animation property)

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

typedef enum {
    CustomViewAnimationTransitionNone,
    CustomViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft,
    CustomViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight,
    CustomViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp,
    CustomViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown,
    CustomViewAnimationTransitionFadeIn,
    CustomViewAnimationTransitionMoveIn,
    CustomViewAnimationTransitionPush,
    CustomViewAnimationTransitionReveal
} CustomViewAnimationTransition;

#define CustomViewAnimationSubtypeFromRight kCATransitionFromRight
#define CustomViewAnimationSubtypeFromLeft kCATransitionFromLeft
#define CustomViewAnimationSubtypeFromTop kCATransitionFromTop
#define CustomViewAnimationSubtypeFromBottom kCATransitionFromBottom

@interface UINavigationController(Additions)

- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withCustomTransition:(CustomViewAnimationTransition)transition subtype:(NSString*)subtype;

- (void)popViewControllerWithCustomTransition:(CustomViewAnimationTransition)transition subtype:(NSString*)subtype;
- (void)popToRootViewControllerWithCustomTransition:(CustomViewAnimationTransition)transition subtype:(NSString*)subtype;
- (void)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withCustomTransition:(CustomViewAnimationTransition)transition subtype:(NSString*)subtype;

@end
```

This second part you need to put in the implementation file:

```
#import "UINavigationController_Additions.h"

@interface UINavigationController()

- (void)standardAnimationWithController:(UIViewController*)viewController
                                duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
                                options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options
                                changesBlock:(void (^)(void))block;
- (void)coreAnimationWithController:(UIViewController*)viewController
                                duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
                                type:(NSString*)type
                                subtype:(NSString*)subtype
                                changesBlock:(void (^)(void))block;
@end

@implementation UINavigationController(Additions)

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark pushing

- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withCustomTransition:(CustomViewAnimationTransition)transition subtype:(NSString*)subtype {
    switch (transition) {
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionNone:{
            [self standardAnimationWithController:viewController duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                                            changesBlock:^{
                                                [self pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
                                            }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft:{
            [self standardAnimationWithController:viewController duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                                            changesBlock:^{
                                                [self pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
                                            }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight:{
            [self standardAnimationWithController:viewController duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                                            changesBlock:^{
                                                [self pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
                                            }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp:{
            [self standardAnimationWithController:viewController duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                                            changesBlock:^{
                                                [self pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
                                            }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown:{
            [self standardAnimationWithController:viewController duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
                                            changesBlock:^{
                                                [self pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
                                            }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionFadeIn:{
            [self coreAnimationWithController:viewController duration:.5 type:kCATransitionFade subtype:nil
                                 changesBlock:^{
                                     [self pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
                                 }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionMoveIn:{
            [self coreAnimationWithController:viewController duration:.5 type:kCATransitionMoveIn subtype:subtype
                                 changesBlock:^{
                                     [self pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
                                 }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionPush:{
            [self coreAnimationWithController:viewController duration:.5 type:kCATransitionPush subtype:subtype
                                 changesBlock:^{
                                     [self pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
                                 }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionReveal:{
            [self coreAnimationWithController:viewController duration:.5 type:kCATransitionReveal subtype:subtype
                                 changesBlock:^{
                                     [self pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
                                 }];
            break;}
        default:{
            break;}
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark popping

- (void)popViewControllerWithCustomTransition:(CustomViewAnimationTransition)transition subtype:(NSString*)subtype {
    switch (transition) {
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionNone:{
            [self standardAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                                     changesBlock:^{
                                         [self popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                                     }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft:{
            [self standardAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                                     changesBlock:^{
                                         [self popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                                     }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight:{
            [self standardAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                                     changesBlock:^{
                                         [self popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                                     }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp:{
            [self standardAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                                     changesBlock:^{
                                         [self popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                                     }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown:{
            [self standardAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
                                     changesBlock:^{
                                         [self popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                                     }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionFadeIn:{
            [self coreAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 type:kCATransitionFade subtype:nil
                                 changesBlock:^{
                                     [self popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                                 }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionMoveIn:{
            [self coreAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 type:kCATransitionMoveIn subtype:subtype
                                 changesBlock:^{
                                     [self popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                                 }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionPush:{
            [self coreAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 type:kCATransitionPush subtype:subtype
                                 changesBlock:^{
                                     [self popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                                 }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionReveal:{
            [self coreAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 type:kCATransitionReveal subtype:subtype
                                 changesBlock:^{
                                     [self popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                                 }];
            break;}
        default:{
            break;}
    }
}

- (void)popToRootViewControllerWithCustomTransition:(CustomViewAnimationTransition)transition subtype:(NSString*)subtype {
    switch (transition) {
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionNone:{
            [self standardAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                                     changesBlock:^{
                                         [self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                                     }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft:{
            [self standardAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                                     changesBlock:^{
                                         [self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                                     }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight:{
            [self standardAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                                     changesBlock:^{
                                         [self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                                     }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp:{
            [self standardAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                                     changesBlock:^{
                                         [self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                                     }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown:{
            [self standardAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
                                     changesBlock:^{
                                         [self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                                     }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionFadeIn:{
            [self coreAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 type:kCATransitionFade subtype:nil
                                 changesBlock:^{
                                     [self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                                 }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionMoveIn:{
            [self coreAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 type:kCATransitionMoveIn subtype:subtype
                                 changesBlock:^{
                                     [self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                                 }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionPush:{
            [self coreAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 type:kCATransitionPush subtype:subtype
                                 changesBlock:^{
                                     [self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                                 }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionReveal:{
            [self coreAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 type:kCATransitionReveal subtype:subtype
                                 changesBlock:^{
                                     [self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                                 }];
            break;}
        default:{
            break;}
    }    
}

- (void)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withCustomTransition:(CustomViewAnimationTransition)transition subtype:(NSString*)subtype {
    switch (transition) {
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionNone:{
            [self standardAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                                     changesBlock:^{
                                         [self popToViewController:viewController animated:NO];
                                     }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft:{
            [self standardAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                                     changesBlock:^{
                                         [self popToViewController:viewController animated:NO];
                                     }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight:{
            [self standardAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                                     changesBlock:^{
                                         [self popToViewController:viewController animated:NO];
                                     }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp:{
            [self standardAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                                     changesBlock:^{
                                         [self popToViewController:viewController animated:NO];
                                     }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown:{
            [self standardAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
                                     changesBlock:^{
                                         [self popToViewController:viewController animated:NO];
                                     }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionFadeIn:{
            [self coreAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 type:kCATransitionFade subtype:nil
                                 changesBlock:^{
                                     [self popToViewController:viewController animated:NO];
                                 }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionMoveIn:{
            [self coreAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 type:kCATransitionMoveIn subtype:subtype
                                 changesBlock:^{
                                     [self popToViewController:viewController animated:NO];
                                 }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionPush:{
            [self coreAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 type:kCATransitionPush subtype:subtype
                                 changesBlock:^{
                                     [self popToViewController:viewController animated:NO];
                                 }];
            break;}
        case CustomViewAnimationTransitionReveal:{
            [self coreAnimationWithController:nil duration:.5 type:kCATransitionReveal subtype:subtype
                                 changesBlock:^{
                                     [self popToViewController:viewController animated:NO];
                                 }];
            break;}
        default:{
            break;}
    }        
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark private

- (void)standardAnimationWithController:(UIViewController*)viewController
                                duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
                                options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options
                                changesBlock:(void (^)(void))block {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:duration options:options animations:block completion:NULL];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)coreAnimationWithController:(UIViewController*)viewController
                                duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
                                type:(NSString*)type
                                subtype:(NSString*)subtype
                                changesBlock:(void (^)(void))block {
    CATransition* trans = [CATransition animation];
    [trans setDuration:duration];
    [trans setType:type];
    [trans setSubtype:subtype];
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:trans forKey:kCATransition];
    block();
}

@end
```

Comment: oh! should i include it to my custom NavigationController?

Comment: Nope, just paste this code into the category files (.h for the interface, .m for implementation) and make sure they are available in your project. Then import the header file wherever you want to use the category method. If you're having trouble understanding how category works see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html).

Comment: I've divided the code into two, just paste the first part into the header and the second into the implementation file.

Comment: i did it in the way you tell about. may be the problem in some other reasons

Comment: Do you actually import the `UINavigationController+Additions.h` in the file where you call `[self.navigationController pushViewController:places withCustomTransition:CustomViewAnimationTransitionPush subtype:CustomViewAnimationSubtypeFromLeft];`?

Comment: Good job, it works really well. Is there a way to get rid of the fade out on the exiting View when using CustomViewAnimationTransitionPush?

Comment: @DJohnson, interesting, I didn't notice that before. I gave it a try but I was not able to fix this properly. As long as you want to push from right, you can just override the lines 61-64 and just do the standard push there.

Comment: Xcode 7.2 generates this build warning "Category is implementing a method which will also be implemented by its primary class" in reference to the standardAnimationWithController:duration:options:changesBlock method.  How to prevent this warning without resorting to pragma clang diagnostic?

Comment: @lifjoy Seems to be a name collision for that specific method, just change the name of the method in the category to something else and see if the warning is gone. This method should not be used outside of the category source anyway, so this change should be easy.

Comment: Thanks lawicko, but renaming the methods did not suppress the warning.  I resolved the issue by commenting out the @interface UINavigationController() definition block at the top of UINavigationController_Additions.m since its methods are not referenced by outside callers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `QuartzCore.framework` to your target to solve `_OBJC_CLASS_$_CATransition` error.

Answer (score 0):

I recently tackled creating my own transition, here's the reusable library I made:

https://github.com/travisjeffery/TRVSNavigationControllerTransition

And here's my [blog post](http://travisjeffery.com/b/2012/10/making-custom-transitions-between-uiviewcontrollers-and-uinavigationcontrollertransition/) talking about how to make your own transition.

The basic idea is pretty simple though, just take a CALayer snapshot of the navigationController's (current) view, then push/pop the view off without animation, take a CALayer snapshot of the new view and then add your own animations to those layers and then remove those layers once the animation is completed.

Comment: Taking the snapshot seriously delays the transition. Especially on older devices.