# How to set push and pop view controller flow

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

In my application,i want to set pop view controller right to left.Where as the push view controller flow left to right ,That fine .I tried this [How to change the Push and Pop animations in a navigation based app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215672/how-to-change-the-push-and-pop-animations-in-a-navigation-based-app) but it works by transition animation view i want without animation pop view controller right to left?please help to solve

Comment: What do you mean by without animation pop view controller right to left? Do you want to just disable animations? Can you please clarify.

Comment: Please be clearer , cant make head or tail of wat ur saying ...

Comment: @ACB i just want by default animation while clicking the pushview as same in pop view but right to left with Timing

Comment: In that case what was the issue with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215672/how-to-change-the-push-and-pop-animations-in-a-navigation-based-app and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480458/change-animation-transition? Why did you choose not to use that?

Answer (score 3):

for pop effect

```
ViewController *back = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
NSMutableArray *vcs =  [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[vcs insertObject:back atIndex:[vcs count]-1];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:vcs animated:NO];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Here in this code you push the viewcontroller but it gives effect of  left to right.

Comment: Sorry i dont know about that. but if this answer is helpful to you than you can accept it or upward the point of answer. thanks