# Animation in transition style in push segue?

Tags: iphone, animation, storyboard, transition, pushviewcontroller

i want to use push segue in my app but storyboard is not allowing me to change its transition style other that default.

Is there any way to change its transition style to some other style?

Answer (score 1):

There sure are! Though not super simple, the steps in this answer should allow you to accomplish your objective.

[Change animation transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480458/change-animation-transition)

Good luck!